# Postgres table select query is too slow

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Am having a gps-tracking application.It has a table named gps_vehicle_data where incoming gps data are stored frequently. I query this table at frequent intervals to process it as it contains just raw data. Recently, I am witnessing long delays in the execution of select statements on the table. Below is the results of EXPLAIN. I also tried doing VACUUM & pasting the results below. What could be the reason?

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) select * from gps_vehicle_data;

                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on gps_vehicle_data  (cost=0.00..130818.81 rows=1400881 width=1483) (actual time=209.129..62488.822 rows=9635 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=13132 read=103678 dirtied=67 written=25
 Planning time: 0.050 ms
 Execution time: 62500.850 ms
```

**VACUUM OUTPUT.**

```
VACUUM (VERBOSE,ANALYSE) gps_vehicle_data;
INFO:  vacuuming "public.gps_vehicle_data"
INFO:  index "gps_vehicle_data_pkey" now contains 1398939 row versions in 10509 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU 0.07s/0.09u sec elapsed 9.38 sec.
INFO:  index "gps_vehicle_data_status_idx" now contains 1398939 row versions in 4311 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU 0.03s/0.04u sec elapsed 4.50 sec.
INFO:  index "gps_vehicle_data_url_data_idx" now contains 1399004 row versions in 98928 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU 0.76s/0.88u sec elapsed 82.74 sec.
INFO:  index "gps_vehicle_data_createdon_idx" now contains 1399007 row versions in 3946 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU 0.00s/0.02u sec elapsed 1.92 sec.
INFO:  "gps_vehicle_data": found 0 removable, 1402484 nonremovable row versions in 116884 out of 116884 pages
DETAIL:  1401490 dead row versions cannot be removed yet.
There were 143431 unused item pointers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU 1.70s/2.38u sec elapsed 200.61 sec.
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_toast.pg_toast_17296"
INFO:  index "pg_toast_17296_index" now contains 0 row versions in 1 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU 0.00s/0.00u sec elapsed 0.01 sec.
INFO:  "pg_toast_17296": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 out of 0 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet.
There were 0 unused item pointers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU 0.00s/0.00u sec elapsed 0.01 sec.
INFO:  analyzing "public.gps_vehicle_data"
INFO:  "gps_vehicle_data": scanned 30000 of 116884 pages, containing 335 live rows and 359656 dead rows; 335 rows in sample, 1042851 estimated total rows
VACUUM
```

Comment: Your table contains a **lot** of dead rows that can't be cleaned up ("1401490 dead row versions cannot be removed yet"). The most likely cause for that is that you have connections that are `idle in transaction` preventing the cleanup of the old rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You read over 100000 blocks to get some 10000 rows, that means that your table consists almost entirely of nothing (it is suffering from *table bloat*).

The table must have contained many more data at some time, and most of these have been deleted since, which caused the bloat.

As @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned, some of your rows cannot be reclaimed because there are some old transactions blocking them, but while `VACUUM` will free dead rows, it will not reorganize the table to get rid of the bloat.

The correct solution in this case is to use `VACUUM (FULL, ANALYZE) gps_vehicle_data` (the `ANALYZE` is just for good measure since it looks like your table statistics are off), which will reorganize the table. Be warned, however, that all access to the table is blocked while `VACUUM (FULL)` is running.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I shutdown all app servers connected to the db & ran VACUUM(VERBOZE,ANALYZE) & it deleted the free dead rows. Now the queries are lot faster. I shall also try VACUUM(FULL, ANALYZE) during the maintenance hour.

Comment: Don't run `VACUUM (FULL)` regularly. Normally your tables should never get bloated unless you do a mass delete.

Comment: Yes, I do mass deletion once the raw data is processed. Is that okay in that case or does it have any issues?

Comment: Sure it is ok, only the table will be blocked during `VACUUM (FULL)`. If you empty the table, you can use `TRUNCATE` instead of `DELETE`. You can also leave the table bloated if that is no problem, the next `INSERT`s will use the empty space.